# ACL for SNMPv3 operations

Tags: snmp

Can I use acl for SNMPv3 operation?. My DUT has provision to bind acl with community string only. I don't find any cli to bind acl with snmp users.

Answer (score 2):

I can't help or fix your device if it doesn't offer you interfaces to manipulate the ACL in it.

But if it supports SNMPv3 then it is required to support the [VACM](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3415.txt) ACL.  Reading through [Net-SNMP's documentation](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/Vacm) about it may help you learn, even though the configuration is likely different from your DUT.  But the DUT should implement the same concepts using a different set of configuration or CLI commands.

If there is no CLI to set it up, you may need to use SNMP itself to set it up.  If so, there are other [command line utilities like snmpvacm](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmpvacm.html) to invoke externally that may help you.